# Laravel 4 model events the same as regular events

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Are model events the same as regular events. And do you place model events as regular events? I'm trying to create a profile row when a user registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle model events via some [helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) or using [model observers](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers).

But yes, behind the scenes, these events are fired Laravel's event dispatcher, so technically you could bind functions to those events via the `Event` facade, too.